# SharePoint JavaScript development without doing add-ins?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-jsom

I have to create some custom functionality in SharePoint 2013 using JSOM/REST, but I don't have the administrative rights to publish an add-in to the site.

What is the procedure for creating JSOM/REST code on a SharePoint page without doing an add-in?

I'm not sure if this the best way, but I have created an .aspx page and loaded this page in the "Page viewer" web part, this then loads the .aspx page in an iframe, this mimics an app.

Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the content editor web part or the script editor web part to just insert javascript/jsom in your application page